# How to print values from a tuple next to each other after permutation?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

Task:

You are given a string "S". 
 Your task is to print all possible permutations of size  of the string in 
 lexicographic sorted order.

Input Format:

A single line containing the space separated string "S" and the integer 
 value "K".

Sample Code explaining how permutations work(I used one of these later):

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> print permutations(['1','2','3'])
<itertools.permutations object at 0x02A45210>
>>>
>>> print list(permutations(['1','2','3']))
[('1', '2', '3'), ('1', '3', '2'), ('2', '1', '3'), ('2', '3', '1'), 
('3', '1', '2'), ('3', '2', '1')]
>>>
>>> print list(permutations(['1','2','3'],2))
[('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '1'), ('2', '3'), ('3', '1'), ('3', 
'2')]
>>>
>>> print list(permutations('abc',3))
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a'), 
('c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'a')]
```

Sample Input:

HACK 2

Sample Output:

One under another:
 AC
 AH
 AK
 CA
 CH
 CK
 HA
 HC
 HK
 KA
 KC
 KH

Explanation:

All possible size 2 permutations of the string "HACK" are printed in 
 lexicographic sorted order.

Here is my Code:

```
from itertools import permutations
S = input().split()
K = "".join(sorted(A[0].upper()))
C = int(A[1])

for i in permutations(S,C):
    print(i)
```

But the output is:
    ('A', 'C')
    ('A', 'H')
    ('A', 'K')
    ('C', 'A')
    ('C', 'H')
    ('C', 'K')
    ('H', 'A')
    ('H', 'C')
    ('H', 'K')
    ('K', 'A')
    ('K', 'C')
    ('K', 'H')

How to print the elements of these tuples without parentheses and quotes in this way?:
AC
AH
AK one under another.

Note that it has to work when user type: "hack 3" or "anything x", where x is the number of elements of every element from permutaion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.join()` and print them like a strings:

```
from itertools import permutations

a = list(permutations('hack',2))
# In a more pythonic way you can do:
# a = permutations('hack', 2)
# Then you can include it in a foor loop
for k in a:
    print("".join(k).upper(), end = " ")
```

Output:

```
HA HC HK AH AC AK CH CA CK KH KA KC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in permutations(S,C):
    print(i)
```

to

```
for i in permutations(S,C):
    for j in range(C):
        print(i[j], end='')
```

I'm assuming you're using Python 3.

Comment: Ok I worked it out earlier and it works when you write "hack 2", where "2" means you want to permutate them into 2 elements, but when you write "hack 3" or "anything x" where x is any number less than len of string, it doesnt work. It has to be universal code.

Comment: @JeyKey Edited to suit dynamic x

Comment: Almost. The output is: "ACAHAKCACHCKHAHCHKKAKCKH" How to print AC and under it AH and so on..?

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations

A = input().split()
B = "".join(sorted(A[0].upper()))
C = int(A[1])

a = list(permutations(B,C))

for k in a:
    print("".join(k))
```

We got it! Thanks to @Chiheb Nexus!

Comment: By the way, do you know why I have to sort it in step B = "".join(sorted(A[0].upper()))? Why it isn't sorted by permutations()  in lexicographic order itself?

Comment: It depends of your input. Have you an example ?

Comment: I tried with "hack 2". When the code is B = "".join(A[0].upper()), the output is: HA
HC
HK
AH
AC
AK
CH
CA
CK
KH
KA
KC
When the code is B = "".join(sorted(A[0].upper())), the output is: 
AC
AH
AK
CA
CH
CK
HA
HC
HK
KA
KC
KH

Comment: With an input equal to `"hack 2"` , `"".join(sorted(A[0].split()))` is `"".join(['a', 'c', 'h', 'k'])` which is: `'achk'`. However, "".join(A[0].split())` is `'hack'`. So, if you try to find the permutations of the first syntax within `C`which is equal to `2`, you'll find the permutations of `achk` and the second is the permutations of `hack`